# Convex Hull of Sampled Random Points

Tags: probability, geometry, probability-theory

Consider $N$ i.i.d. random points $x_1,x_2,..., x_N\in \mathbb{R}^n$, sampled from a given distribution $d$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $\mathcal{C}_x \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be the convex hull of these points $\{x_1,x_2,..., x_N\}$.

Then consider $N$ new, again i.i.d., random points $y_1,y_2,..., y_N\in \mathbb{R}^n$, sampled from the same distribution $d$.

Questions.

- What is the "Expected Value" for the Number of Points $y_i$ not in $\mathcal{C}_x$?
- If $\mathcal{C}_y$ is the convex hull of the points $\{y_1,y_2,..., y_N\}$, what is the "Expected Value" of the ration between the two volume, i.e. $\text{vol}(\mathcal{C}_y)/\text{vol}(\mathcal{C}_x)$?

  - How do the above answers change if $\mathcal{C}_x$ is based on $N_1$ points and $\mathcal{C}_y$ is based on $N_2>N_1$ points?

Comment. The aim of these questions is trying to understand the behaviour of the convex hull of some samples. Moreover, it would interesting to relate $\text{vol}(\mathcal{C}_y)$ to $\text{vol}(\mathcal{C}_x)$, especially for $N_2>N_1$, in order to "estimate" $\text{conv}\{y_1,y_2,..., y_{N_2}\}$ based on $\text{conv}\{x_1,x_2,..., x_{N_1}\}$. I do not know what to read to address this arguments.